\newkeytheoremstyle: styling with parameters
I would like to define a parametrized style with one or more parameters to build several similar boxed environments with only few visual changes (the main one is about the color used).
Is it feasible with the \newkeytheoremstyle of the brand-new package keytheorems?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

\tcbset{
  thmstyle/.style={
    colback=red!5,          % Red as a parameter
    colframe=red!35!black},
}
  
\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard}{
  tcolorbox = thmstyle, 
  headpunct = {},
  notebraces={}{}, 
  noteseparator={: }, 
  notefont=\bfseries, 
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
}

\newkeytheorem{test}[
  name=Test,
  style=tcb-standard]
  
\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{test}

\end{document}


The pgfkeys /.style handler allows a single parameterized argument (and you can use more with /.style 2 args, etc.)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

\tcbset{
  thmstyle/.style={
    colback=#1!5,          % Red as a parameter
    colframe=#1!35!black},
}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard}{
  headpunct = {},
  notebraces={}{}, 
  noteseparator={: }, 
  notefont=\bfseries, 
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
}
\newcommand{\projetnewstyle}[1]{%
  \newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard-#1}
    {inherit-style=tcb-standard,tcolorbox={thmstyle=#1}}%
  }
\projetnewstyle{red}
\projetnewstyle{green}

\newkeytheorem{test}[
  name=Test,
  style=tcb-standard-red]

\newkeytheorem{blub}[style=tcb-standard-green]

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{test}
\begin{blub}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{blub}

\end{document}


